# Can Linux Desktop Apps Be Used As The Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, graphics, window, desktop

Similar as to how RetroPie works, can I use a Linux app as my desktop environment? I don't actually need things like an actual desktop and installing apps. I just need to have a clean simple way to run my application and MongoDB on a RaspberryPi.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with an `.xinitrc` that just runs your program. Obviously, if you don't run a window manager you can't manage windows, so you can't resize, move or switch between windows anymore. Make sure your program doesn't open windows or popups.

Comment: You could use minimal desktop environments, there are plenty of them out there. This page has a good listing of the many available Linux Desktop environments: [Desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: *"**YES**, but..."*

### X VS Desktop Environments

**You will need a graphical server, but you can avoid using a Desktop Environment!**

In Linux, your graphical programs relies (at least) on an X server to work properly. This means you'll never find (if not specifically crafted as a programming exercise) totally independent applications with custom internal libraries and a bult-in environment.

That exactly why X were invented!

But X is NOT your Desktop Environment... in fact, DE runs **over** X.

Yet, you can go very minimal with some applications **using X without any DE.**

---

### Let's going minimalistic:

I assume you maybe want a fully functional web browser.
Let's take a common example, [Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/407043/is-it-possible-to-run-graphical-applications-such-as-firefox-without-installing):

- Firefox **requires** X server. 
  You'll need to manually install X server first, then Firefox.
  Either way, if you can rely on a package manager, it should install the bare minimum of the packages, including the X server.

Then, you just need to run the X server without the desktop environnment. Basically something like:

```
$ X
```

Then you just start Firefox in this X server:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 firefox
```

You can switch from the X server and the framebuffer by using **CTRL+ALT+F1** and **CTRL+ALT+F7**.

So, in some way, you could also use all seven framebuffers (from F1 to F7) to handle up to 7 graphical programs in 7 different X server processes.

---

*Please notice that this is not the way many applications are intended to run... you'll have to dig down and investigate your application as it may not work as intended sometimes without a proper DE below it*

Comment: Alright thanks! I guess I'll actually just run it as a normal application because I might need terminal access.